# How many consumers can i have? (Spring-boot + RabbitMq)

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using Spring Boot with RabbitMq, and a question came up, is there a limited number of consumers I can create?
Where do I find this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spring-Amqp` has no limit for consumer number.

But usually it will be restricted by other things. For example, if you use `SimpleMessageListner`, one consumer corresponds to one thread. When your number of consumers is large, your app may not be able to create so many threads, resulting in `OOM: unable to create new native thread`.

```
    // OOM in my computer
    @RabbitListener(queues = "testq", concurrency = "10000-10000")
    public void listen() {
    }
```

If you use a `CachingConnectionFactory`([connections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#connections)), set `CacheMode` to `CONNECTION`, maybe your rabbitmq server cannot carry a very large number of consumers ([probably hit the maximum number of file descriptors.](https://serverfault.com/questions/758055/increase-max-number-of-consumers-on-rabbitmq)), and your app may not be able to connect to rabbitmq.